# sdkman behind proxy: install grails fails with 'curl received HTTP 403 from proxy after CONNECT'

Tags: grails, curl, proxy, sdkman

Used sdkman to install several packages (had to set proxy and proxy-user in .curlrc to negotiate the corporate proxy). When I tried installing grails and groovyserv they both fail with curl Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT.

I think I'm negotiating the proxy OK (because the other installs worked), so does this indicate that there is something different at the end server giving me the grails content, or is my proxy objecting to the grails content.

Any advice on how to debug / fix would be appreciated

Windows XP, cygwin (very recent download), Corporate proxy

$ sdk current

Using:
gradle: 2.7
groovy: 2.4.4
lazybones: 0.8.1
vertx: 3.0.0

$ sdk install grails

Downloading: grails 3.0.7

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: do you have user/password defined in your proxy setting ?

Answer (score 4):

After opening your Cygwin command prompt window, type in this:

**`export http_proxy=http://yourusername:yourpassword@host:port/`**

For example:

**`export http_proxy=http://superman:batman@111.112.113.114:8080/`**

Hope this will work for you (only worked for me with half of the available candidates, sad).

Comment: Wouldn't work for me until I put port 80 and the slash on the end.... (windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

I my case to work behind a corporate proxy.

- set up proxy env variables

export http_proxy="http://user:pwd@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:yy"

export https_proxy="http://user:pwd@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:yy"

- some corporate proxies use certificates signed by their own CA's. you should install  the root CA's.  Another not recomened option is adding **sdkman_insecure_ssl=true** to ~/.sdkman/etc/config

Answer (score 1):

I added 'verbose' to my .curlrc and spotted the following:

- Issue another request to this URL: 'http://dl.bintray.com/aalmiray/Griffon/griffon-1.5.0-bin.zip' - paste URL into my browser and it downloads (but throws away the download... love life inside a corporate ;-)
- Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/download/v3.0.8/grails-3.0.8.zip' - paste URL into my browser and it's blocked - no corporate access to github is allowed... grrrr

I wonder if the Grails team would consider using bintray instead of github?

Comment: except that some of us have bintray blocked and github open ;-)